# Nethereum - get require output from failed transaction

Tags: solidity, nethereum

I can use Remix and get the output from the require function.

```
require(balanceOf[src] >= wad, "insufficient-balance");
```

If the require function fails, I get the "insufficient-balance" message.

Using Nethereum, I don't get the "insufficient-balance" from the Exception message nor do I get the "insufficient-balance" from the TransactionReceipt. I can view the transaction in an explorer, so I can see the reason it's failing. What I would like to do is post these error messages to my users in case there is an error.

I do get a 1 or 0 from the TransactionReceipt.Status.Value, so I can do something like this.

//1 for success, 2 for failure

```
if (receipt.Status.Value == 1)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        else
        {
            //Do something to get the Status from the Transaction Details            
        }
```

Neither of these methods work.

```
RequireMessage = receipt.Logs.ToString();

RequireMessage = await web3.Eth.GetContractTransactionErrorReason.SendRequestAsync(TransactionHash);
```

Any help is much appreciated. I'm using Nethereum.Web3, Nethereum.MetaMask.Blazor and Nethereum.UI 4.8.0.